# Android imageview longpress hint

Tags: android

How can i create hint for an imageview/imagebutton like google play?
please see below image

[image]

it shows a toast below search icon when we have long click on search icon,please advice

Comment: This is not something you need to work for,  it will automatically show suggestion to you when you put any menu item in toolbar. you must add this line in your menu item tag. `android:title="Search Google Play"`

Comment: check @KrishnaJ answer is the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use toolbar menu and in menu file:`android:title="Search Google Play"` this attribute.

**For Example:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   tools:context="com.example.drawer.EditTransaction" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_delete"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Delete"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_delete"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

You can place tool bar and menu like this:

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    this.toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white100);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Edit Transaction");
```

For click event Of this and work that menu do:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.edit_transaction, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_delete:
        exitConfirmDialog();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: thanks , how can i implement toolbar menu?
i am using toolbar without actionbar, and as i know we cannot use toolbar when we are using NoActionbar themes

Answer (score 6):

For ImageView you may use:

```
android:tooltipText="This is tip"
```

it works only in android 8.0 and higher (API level 26 and higher)